# Is there any way to use one method inside another method in OOP?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to make a turtle program in Python using OOP but I am unable to call one method inside another method. I wanted to call the square method inside the design method.

```
import turtle
my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

class Circle:

   def __init__(self,length,angle,speed,angle_turn):

      self.length = length
      self.angle = angle
      self.speed = speed
      self.angle_turn = angle_turn

   def square(self):

      for i in range(4):

         my_turtle.speed(self.speed)
         my_turtle.forward(self.length)
         my_turtle.left(self.angle)

   def design(self):

      for i in range(60):

         square()
         my_turtle.right(self.angle_turn)
```

Comment: You need to call the `square` method of `self`: `self.square()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor your code as such

```
import turtle

class Circle:

   def __init__(self,length,angle,speed,angle_turn):

      self.length = length
      self.angle = angle
      self.speed = speed
      self.angle_turn = angle_turn
      self.my_turtle = turtle.Turtle()

   def square(self):

      for i in range(4):

         self.my_turtle.speed(self.speed)
         self.my_turtle.forward(self.length)
         self.my_turtle.left(self.angle)

   def design(self):

      for i in range(60):

         self.square()
         self.my_turtle.right(self.angle_turn)
```

This way your class is not dependent on external variable my_turtle.